# I can not unselect a checkbox on this template with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a checkbox which selects the value "5303" in a object.

```
<input value="5303" data-bind="checked: checkTest"
                        type="checkbox" name="test" id="2"><span
                        class="label-text"> TEST</span>
```

`$scope.checkTest= ko.observableArray();`

How do I unselect the checkbox on this template by code?

Comment: How does it make sense to bind to an array here?

Comment: @connexo to be capable of holding multiple values?

Comment: How can a checkbox hold multiple values?

Comment: An array can hold values of multiple checkboxes. The 2nd example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a checkbox which selects the value "5303" in a object

By this you mean the value '5303' gets inserted into the observableArray `checkTest`, correct?

To unselect the checkbox by code, update its value with an empty array:

```
$scope.checkTest([]);
```